Is it possible to fill an arbitrarily large hex grid completely given these rules? #2
Based off of this.
Lets say you have two players, Red and Blue, that alternate filling an arbitrarily large hexagonal grid of tessellated hexagons with pieces of their color. Hexagons can either be filled or empty.
A piece maybe be placed on an empty hexagon (filling it) as long as that empty hexagon meets BOTH of these conditions:

No more than two filled adjacencies.
The filled adjacencies contain an equal number of Red and Blue pieces.

Is there a way to fill up the grid completely?

I claim the answer is

 no

because

 the last cell you fill must have at least 3 adjacent already-filled cells.


How did I miss this......
